# GMAIL not showing images in email from local Homestead and Laravel dev env

Tags: php, email, gmail, homestead

I have tried a few different approaches but I cannot get this to work. I have a local dev env with Laravel 5.2 on Homesetad. I am getting my app sending emails for registration (using Sendgrid) and all works well except the images are not displayed.

Understandably, the images are local to my Homestead setup, and I have a hosts redirect in Windows to the Homestead IP for the app url. The GMAIL client is also running on this machine.

GMAIL prepends a url to the images from what I see on inspect and this stops the images working.

In my blade / HTML i include my images like this:

```
<img src="{!! url(env('ACC_IMAGE_PATH').$invite['organisation_logo']) !!}" style="max-width: 125px; max-height: 40px;">
```

In GMAIL the image HTML looks like this:

```
<img src="https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/hGSRlRznq4ikfV3nCgMn4WGKm88l-Dg5zCJbqPfp5HVyxtFr6hWNXcT3nDl4SQX6LfbaJNgRqzKqEv-zWNbDSqwHiyYU3jR3zsNxNbMMYYiLAXQu9btmyqxxTLdNs5E=s0-d-e1-ft#http://mylocaldev.app/img/acc/81254bfa-fd9f-4270-9b3c-7105e2690bec.png" style="max-width:125px;max-height:40px" class="CToWUd">
```

If I delete the prepended URL the image shows OK like this:

```
<img src="http://mylocaldev.app/img/acc/81254bfa-fd9f-4270-9b3c-7105e2690bec.png" style="max-width:125px;max-height:40px" class="CToWUd">
```

I cannot seem to find much relating to Homestead / GMAIL and images. Is there a trick I am missing on how I add the images? Can it be done? Thanks.